# Trigger Firebase Cloud Function on linkWithCredential()

Tags: javascript, firebase, firebase-authentication, google-cloud-functions

I'm trying set custom claims for users who have a company email. 
Everything works fine when I use .onCreate() trigger, but since I log in users anonymously, I don't know how I can trigger this function at the right time (at signup, when the email is available).

Is my only resort to use a https callable cloud function ? I'd rather not expose this one.

Is there another way to set custom claims for special login cases i'm unaware of ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The only Authentication triggers that are available for Cloud Functions are when the user account is first created, and when it gets deleted. There is no trigger to run a function when an email gets added or verified, not when two identity providers are linked to the same account.

The standard way to do what you want is to use another trigger type (such as a callable function as you already said), validate in there that the user is indeed entitled to the custom claim, and then add that claim to their profile.